# How can I write a python function wrapper, that loads the result if the hash of the input arguments is known?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Many functions in my machine learning environment are deterministic. Meaning, for the same input they always have exactly the same output.

As I often call those function with the same argument, I'd like to automatically detect if the computation was done before. If yes, reload from a pickle file, else calculate and store to a pickle file with the hash of the arguments.

How can I implement that? With a wrapper class? A decorator?

Comment: file access are not free either, so are you shure you want to use files as cache ? Based on the execution context, there might be better choices (in process memory, in memory external cache, persistant external cache etc). Else, this pattern (in it's generic form) is named "memoization", most example you'll find will use "in process memory" caching but can easily be adapted to some external cache.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/svetlin-mladenov/fcache. Spoiler, I am the creator of this library.

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov your lib seems interesting but will not work in a distributed environment, which is becoming the standard for computation-heavy tasks. I think you should extend it to allow the use of memcache or redis as shared (and eventually persistant in the case of redis) cache store, or at least provide a mean to implement one own's cache support and make it configurable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a decorator that updates a list with the name of each function called to later be used in the wrapper:

```
import pickle
called_functs = []
def called(f):
  def call_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
     if f.__name__ in called_functs:
        data = pickle.load(open('filename.txt'))
        #do something with data
     else:
        global called_functs
        called_functs.append(f.__name__)
        pickle.dump([args, kwargs, f(*args, **kwargs)], open('filename.txt', 'w'))
   return call_wrapper

@called
def backpropagate(*args, **kwargs): #example from a neural net
   pass
   #do something
```

Comment: I downvoted because of 1/ the use of a global when not necessary, 2/ the use of the `global` statement when it's not necessary, 3/ the use of a relative path for a file access, 4/ the unclosed files, 5/ the fact that the decorator actually never calls the decorated function, and, of course, because using the same name for the `called` list and the decorated function just breaks all uses of `called` inside the decorator function.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thank you for pointing out the name conflict, it is fixed. However, can you suggest a better alternative to the use of globals? Regarding the files, those are just for demonstration purposes based off of what the OP mentioned in his post. Also, I added an a call of the wrapped function, however, I am not sure if the OP merely wants to intercept the passed function arguments and call the function or just perform the former.

Comment: "can you suggest a better alternative to the use of globals" :  yes of course. Oh and BTW: your (now renamed) `called_functs` list only live as long as the process, the point of memoizing to a file is to get a shared and/or persistant cache, which your solution does not provide.

Comment: "Regarding the files, those are just for demonstration purposes" :  SO is read by lot of newcomers or non-programmers that might not know why not closing files is bad. Our duty when we answer here is to try and teach readers good practices along the way. So please don't post faulty code "for example", or _at least_ mentions where and how the code is faulty and what should be handled in real code.